# How to get all the rows affected by a UPDATE query in JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, jdbc

I have an assignment where I need to update records using a `PreparedStatement`. Once the record have been updated as we know update query return count, i.e., number of row affected.

However, instead of the count I want the rows that were affected by update query in response, or at least a list of id values for the rows that were affected.

This my update query.

```
UPDATE  User_Information uInfo SET address = uInfo.contact_number || uInfo.address where uInfo.user_id between ? AND ?;
```

Normally it will return count of row affected but in my case query should return the ids of row or all the row affected.

I have used the `returning` function of PostgreSQL it is working  but is not useful for me in that case.

Comment: You could just do a select statement with the same parameters, and after that do the update.

Comment: Thanks for comment but once my update query run it should return result set

Comment: Then take the id's from the first select statement, do the update, and then do a select statement with the id's you got. Update statements just always return the number of rows that were affected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two way of doing it
1. by passing an array of column name or index of column `prepareStatement`
i.e conn.prepareStatement(sql, new String[] {'id','uname'})
and 
2. by using Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS in  `prepareStatement`.

My code is for this i.e as per my requirement i have developed my code you can have a look for better idea.

```
private static final String UPDATE_USER_QUERY= "UPDATE  User_Information uInfo SET address = uInfo.contact_number || uInfo.address where uInfo.user_id between ? AND ?;";
//pst = connection.prepareStatement(UPDATE_USER_QUERY,columnNames);
pst = connection.prepareStatement(UPDATE_USER_QUERY,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet rst = pst.getGeneratedKeys();
List<UserInformation> userInformationList = new ArrayList<UserInformation>();
UserInformation userInformation;

while (rst.next()){
 userInformation = new UserInformation();

 userInformation.setUserId(rst.getLong("user_id"));
 userInformation.setUserName(rst.getString("user_name"));
 userInformation.setUserLName(rst.getString("user_lName"));
 userInformation.setAddress(rst.getString("address"));
 userInformation.setContactNumber(rst.getLong("contact_number"));
 userInformationList.add(userInformation);
}
```

That think i need to achieve  in this case.
Hope so this will help you a lot.

Answer (score 6):

> i have used returning function of PostgreSQL but is not useful for me

It should be. Perhaps you were just using it wrong. This code works for me:

```java
sql = "UPDATE table1 SET customer = customer || 'X' WHERE customer LIKE 'ba%' RETURNING id";
try (PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    s.execute();  // perform the UPDATE
    try (ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet()) {
        // loop through rows from the RETURNING clause
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt("id"));  // print the "id" value of the updated row
        }
    }
}
```

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html) indicates that we can also use `RETURNING *` if we want the ResultSet to include the entire updated row.

**Update:**

As @CraigRinger suggests in his comment, the PostgreSQL JDBC driver does actually support `.getGeneratedKeys()` for UPDATE statements too, so this code worked for me as well:

```java
sql = "UPDATE table1 SET customer = customer || 'X' WHERE customer LIKE 'ba%'";
try (PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
    s.execute();  // perform the UPDATE
    try (ResultSet rs = s.getGeneratedKeys()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));  // print the "id" value of the updated row
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks, Craig!

Comment: You can use `RETURNING` directly, but don't need to. The JDBC generated keys interface lets you ask for the same info via the standard JDBC API. (Oh, except the spec says it's ignored for non-INSERT queries, nevermind).

Comment: @CraigRinger Not true, JDBC 4.2 (section 13.6) says: _"a JDBC driver must support the return of autogenerated values for SQL INSERT statements. Some JDBC driver implementations might also support auto-generated values with SQL statements other than INSERT."_. In other words: support is required for `INSERT`, optional for other DML. But the wording in the API doc seems to be confusing.

Comment: RETURNING is only for postgress i have tried it is working fine with RETURNING clause but i want other solution for it and unfortunately all the suggestion are mention her  is not work for me

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use JDBC's support for getting generated keys. See the [`Connection.prepareStatement(String sql, int[] columnIndexes)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,%20int[])) API method, then use [`Statement.getGeneratedKeys()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()) to access the results.

The spec says *"the driver will ignore the array if the SQL statement is not an `INSERT` statement"* but I think PostgreSQL's JDBC driver will actually honour your request with other statement types too.

e.g.

```
PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(sql, new String[] {'id'})
s.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = s.getGeneratedKeys();
```

Otherwise, use `RETURNING`, as Gord Thompson describes.

Comment: The documentation says _"The driver will ignore the array if the SQL statement is not an INSERT statement, **or an SQL statement able to return auto-generated keys (the list of such statements is vendor-specific)**."_ The presence of the comma before the _or_ makes it slightly confusing, but it means that it is allowed to be supported for statements other than `INSERT`.

Comment: Yeah, and IIRC PgJDBC blindly appends `RETURNING` to pretty much anything you send via `PrepareStatement` with generated keys. Including things where it's syntactically nonsensical.

Comment: I had the same problem with Jaybird/Firebird. It turns out that some applications (looking at you, ColdFusion) always use `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`, even for queries.