# Update table and return its column in single query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to run an update query on a table and return one of its columns in a single query. Is it possible to do that? I saw it is possible to do that in C#, but what about Java? Here is the example code:

```
public String updateAndReturn(int field1, int field2) {

    String query = "UPDATE my_table SET field1 = ? WHERE field2 = ? LIMIT 1";

    Connection connection = DbConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection();
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

    preparedStatement.setInt(1, field1); 
    preparedStatement.setInt(2, field2);
    executeUpdate(preparedStatement);

    return field3;  // How?
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all the rows affected by a UPDATE query in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36477916/how-to-get-all-the-rows-affected-by-a-update-query-in-jdbc)

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Comment: This depends on the database you are using. Which one is it?

Comment: Looks like MariaDB or MySQL... which one is it?

Comment: I'm using MySQL.

Comment: @RubioRic you are quick on marking it as a duplicate but they are not the same question and it does not answer my question. MySQL does not support returning clause and the field I need is not the id field.

Comment: Sorry. MySQL nature was added after I marked it as duplicate. Question was about JDBC in general.